# nodejs, expressjs, angular, server-side controller fetching all data, but when called by angular controller, it is not returning anything

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb, express

"findByStaff" and "findOne" are returning correct data, but "findAll" is not returning the data, I am expecting findAll should return all courses from mongodb

```
    $scope.findByStaff = function() {
        $scope.courses = Courses.query();
    };

    $scope.findAll = function() {
        $scope.courses = Courses.query();
    };

    $scope.findOne = function() {
        $scope.course = Courses.get({
            courseId: $routeParams.courseId
        });
    };
```

These functions are in my controller which is looking like:

```
angular.module('courses').controller('CoursesController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Courses',
function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Authentication, Courses) {}
```

Comment: You need to elaborate on your question. Assign a meaningful title and a little more feedback. What does the query look like? What does the data look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using $resources in your service Cources, have you tried to set up parameter isArray = true ?

> isArray – {boolean=} – If true then the returned object for this
>   action is an array, see returns section.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource